# Facebook videos do not start

Tags: firefox, facebook, add-on

I have lately installed  20.04 to my PC I use firefox as default browser I do not know why facebook videos did not start I have tried all kind of facebook video player add ons nothing got to work but youtube videos  are working . What is missing or what is causing this  problem ?
Thank you for your help .

Comment: For some reason the Firefox that came preinstalled was unable to play any media for me. I removed it (`sudo apt remove firefox`) and installed Firefox via snap. That worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , in the meantime  I kept going ahead  to solve the problem and I realized the ffmpeg codec was missing after installing it  all video worked fine without any firefox  add ons